# AttributeError - object has no attribute 'create'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to save a through model which has the following attributes via Django-rest-framework

when sending a POST (I'm trying to create a new instance), I get the following error:

> AttributeError at /api/organisation/provider/
>   'EnabledExternalProvider' object has no attribute 'create'

**any ideas as to what i'm doing incorrectly?**

the through model in question is:

```
class EnabledExternalProvider(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(ExternalProvider, related_name='associatedProvider')
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='associatedOrg')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tenantIdentifier = models.CharField('Tenant identifer for organisation', max_length = 128, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.provider + '-' + self.organisation
```

my view is:

```
class EnabledExternalProvider(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ConnectedServiceSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return EnabledExternalProvider.objects.filter(organisation=self.request.user.organisation_id)

def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    # make sure to catch 404's below
    obj = queryset.get(organisation=self.request.user.organisation_id)
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and my serializer is:

```
class ConnectedServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    provider=ExternalProviderSerializer(read_only=True)
    organisation=OrganisationDetailSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = EnabledExternalProvider
        fields = ( 'organisation', 'enabled', 'tenantIdentifier')
        read_only_fields = ('organisation', 'provider')
```

I'm POSTing the following:

```
{"provider":"1","tenantIdentifier":"9f0e40fe-3d6d-4172-9015-4298684a9ad2","enabled":true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view doesn't have that method because you haven't defined it, or inherited from a class that has it; your mixins provide retrieve and update, but not create.

You could add `mixins.CreateModelMixin` to the inheritance, but at this point you should really be using a [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) instead.

Comment: thanks Daniel. That was it. I'll take a look at ViewSets as well.