# Trying to create multiple objects in nested serializer

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("rollno", "grade")

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade,related_name='StudentList', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField(unique = True)

class GradeTotal(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade, related_name='GradeMarks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    average = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()

class StudentTotal(models.Model):
    rollno = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='StudentMarks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gradeno = models.ForeignKey(GradeTotal, related_name='Fromgrade', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks = models.IntegerField()
```

I am using the model `Grade` to create `GradeTotal` and then `StudentTotal`. The object `StudentTotal` is only created when the foreignkey `grade` of `GradeTotal` and `Student` is same to the instant of `Grade` being used for the process.

To do this I have the following serializer:

```
class StudentDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rollno = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model =StudentTotal
        fields = ('marks', 'rollno' )

class GradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Fromgrade = StudentDataSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = GradeTotal
        fields = ('average', 'total', 'Fromgrade', )

class MultipleGradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    GradeMarks = GradeSerializer(many=True)
    grade = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ("grade", "GradeMarks")

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        g_data = validated_data.pop('GradeMarks')
        for datas in g_data:
            a1 = datas["average"]
            t1 = datas["total"]
            g1 = GradeTotal.objects.create(grade=instance, average=a1, total=t1)
            data2 = datas.pop('Fromgrade')
            for data in data2:
                e1 = data["rollno"]
                r1 = Student.objects.get(rollno=data["rollno"])
                if s1.grade == instance:
                    StudentTotal.create(gradeno = g1, rollno = r1, marks =data["marks"])
        return instance
```

This is the best method I could come up with, but in doing so with the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "grade": "nine",
    "GradeMarks": [
        {
            "average": 10,
            "total": 5,
            "Fromgrade": [
                {
                    "marks": 30,
                    "rollno": "N1 "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following error: `Student matching query does not exist` but I can see the object with `rollno` N1 using the django admin. I am not sure why this is happening. And hence I cannot create an object of `StudentTotal` but can create `GradeTotal`.

In my view, I am using `Grade` as the model and `MultipleGradeSerializer` as the serializer. Any help will be appreciated.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
If I do the following for debugging

`r1 = Student.objects.get(rollno="N1")`, I do not get this error dont know why, but I get the following error:

```
type object 'StudentTotal' has no attribute 'create'.
```

And I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728556/attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute-create) for the second issue, my view already has `mixins.CreateModelMixin`. Additionally, it creates the object `GradeTotal`
Can anyone please clear both the points?

Comment: I did sort the first mistake, it was a noobie mistake, there was space in my JSON payload after N1. But I don't know why I am getting `no attribute 'create'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
StudentTotal.create(gradeno = g1, rollno = r1, marks =data["marks"])
```

should be:

```
StudentTotal.objects.create(gradeno = g1, rollno = r1, marks =data["marks"])
```